# Push div to parent's bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I have a row; inside that row I have 2 col divs. One of the col div is longer than the other one. What is the proper way of moving the second col, so they seem in position.

I don't want to use `bottom: 15px` or `top: 22px` or achieve it with margin because it will make me edit the @media  stuff.

What is the proper way to handle such scenario?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37950/

*Expected*:

[image]

---

More understandable with colors:

[image]

Comment: you want the world to be at the bottom?

Comment: Bottom of the row, yes. Like they are inline. I added an Expected screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap applies a **`margin top of 20px`** for **`h2`** elements. You can overwrite the margin top for the **`h2`** element by defining a class.

```css
.removeTopMargin {
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <h2 class="removeTopMargin">Hello</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <button type="button" class="btn">World</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more detailed answer even though Adrian's solution is cool as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is not the height of the column, but the differences in margins on the h2 tag compared to the button. So you could do something like this

```
h2:first-child {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 34px;
}
```

The line-height would be there to get the alignment correctly with the height of the button... though this might cause other problems if the text were long and responsive. Alternatively, you could give the button whatever margin would be appropriate. Or you could have a column-first-child class.

You'd also have to account for whatever content variations you might have in either place.